# change the color of item appeared in the list view

Tags: android

```
if (clicked_items.contains(obj.get("part_no"))) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
}  
return view;
```

I use above code to change the colors of the  list view item. But this will change the items that are not availble in the clicked_items  Array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add else statement to return other rows to normal,
because of how listView reusing rows, if you dont apply your condition on else statement one row change will effect also the others.

```
 if (clicked_items.contains(obj.get("part_no"))) {

                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

            }  
             else {
                      view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Custom adapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (position % 2 == 0) {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

    } else {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

It gives alternate color for items in listview